# How to use two grep lines in Python

Tags: python-3.x, grep

I have the two lines in bash

```
grep -L "BEGIN RSA PRIVATE KEY" *
grep -l "BEGIN RSA PRIVATE KEY" *
```

And would like to use them in a Python array

I've tried to get it working with a subprocess, but the "*" was not working.

I get a file not found error from grep.

Comment: What do you mean by "have two lines in bash"? Do you want to pass the output of these two commands to a Python list?

Comment: This might help: [How to convert STDIN contents to an array?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/548446/3776858)

Comment: I'm searching for a python version of the 2 lines, because i do not get the wildcard not working via subprocess